# Inherited isolated scope from controller to make a reusable directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I make a inherited isolated scope from controller to make a reusable directive? Here is my sample codes:

```
(function (app) {
    //declare the Template
    var template = function (element, attrs) {
        var htmltext =

            '<select ' + attrs.type +
            ' ng-init="getAll(\'' + attrs.classname +
            '\');" ng-model="' + attrs.model +
            '" ng-options="value.' + attrs.data +
            ' for value in result"></select>';

        return htmltext;
    };

    app.directive('listData', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'listController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            scope: { vm: '=' },
            template: template
        }
    });

}(angular.module('app')));
```

How we can use more than one from this directive (with just one controller) and use the result of functions that controller produces for directive.
In this sample I have a `getAll` function that return `$scope.result` from controller to caller. I wanna use this result with `ng-model` that I gave to each directive.

```
    <div ng-controller="listController">
        <list-data type=""
                   model="person"
                   classname="Person"
                   data="Family" 
                   vm="listController">
        </list-data>
<list-data></list-data>
        <p>{{person.Name}} {{person.Family}}?</p>
```

and the list controller:

```
(function (app) {

    app.controller('listController', ['$scope','myservice',function ($scope, myservice) {

        //Call GetAll Method From Each Class
        $scope.getAll = function (classname) {
            myservice.getAll(classname)
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.result = data;
                    $scope.status = status;
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.result = data;
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
        }   
}(angular.module('app')));
```

and my service:

```
(function (app) {
    app.factory('myservice', function ($http,$q) {
        return {
            getAll: function (classname) {
                try {
                    return $http.get('/api/' + classname + '/GetAll/');
                } catch (e) {
                    window.alert(e.message);
                    //should Send a error to controller
                }
            }
        }
    });
}(angular.module('app')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like that :

```js
(function (app) {
    //declare the Template
    var template = function (element, attrs) {
        var htmltext =

            '<select ' + attrs.type +
            '  ng-model="model" ng-options="value as value[data] for value in from"></select>';

        return htmltext;
    };

    app.directive('listData', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { data: '@',
                     classname:'@',
                     model:'=',
                     from:'=',
                     type:'@',
                     data:'@'
                   },
            template: template,
            replace:true,
        }
    });
    app.controller('TestController', ['$timeout', '$scope', function($timeout, $scope){
       $scope.data = [];
       $timeout(function(){
         $scope.data = [{Family:"FOO", Name:"foo"},{Family:"BAR", Name:"bar"}];
       });// simulate async fetching
    }])
}(angular.module('app', [])));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TestController">
         <h1> this is a test </h1>
         <list-data type=""
                   model="person"
                   classname="Person"
                   from="data"
                   data="Family">
        </list-data>

        <p>{{person.Name}} {{person.Family}}?</p>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Some errors in your directive :

1. You wanted to select a person and showing their Family in the `<select>`. For this you have to use the optional `as` in the `ng-options`.
2. To use properly an isolated scope you have to bind your datas to it, it's easier than using attr, specially if you want your list to be able to change and your directive to be refreshed.

What i have added :

1. A from attribute to your directive, inyour case, this is the list of persons from where you want to select yours.
2. The TestController is your listController which i have not. It simulate an async fetching.

What i have removed :

1. the call to getAll in your directive, this directive handles the picking of one element in a list with some parameters, not from where you fetch it. This should let to the controller of the view and has so been replaced by the from attribute. If you really want to do this in your directive, use the function `link(scope, element, attrs){}` to perform the fetching and bind the data to the scope.

EDIT : As requested, you can bind attributes to scope in link function like this however this work only to read the data, not to change them :

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.value = attrs.myAttr;
    attrs.$observe('myAttr', function(){
      scope.value = attrs.myAttr;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your good Answer
in fact wanna use attrs, i dont want to declare variable in scope {}. 
so the directive works good, but i cant access the $scope of controller in view. 
more details: <p>{{person.Name}} {{person.Family}}?</p> show nothing!

Comment: $scope are different objects for the two listController that you bound, one in ng-controller, one in your directive. Since the directive's one is isolated, it won't be able to acces to the other one. You have to use one/two-way data-binding as i did if you want to be able to use it. Another way would be to set `scope:true` in your directive, and in your link function perform `scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.foo)`. But i think my one is following more the standard of angularJS. Isolated scope are for reusable components, thus they don't have access to parent scopes, only bindings.

Comment: my directive is written to be reusable, think about 2 of them under one controller wanna shown some datas, one of them from person class, one of them from city class.

Comment: The intention is here, however you design is wrong. Furthermore why do you have `ng-controller="listController"` along with the `controller:'listController` in your directive ? that doesn't make sense. Mine is perfeclty reusable as you want. I removed the handling of fetching datas, because this shouldn't be the responsability of the directive. Because you won't be able to handle case where you don't want "all" data but only a filtered part. By moving it out of the directive, now you can :)

Comment: You don't use one controller with many directive. You use directive with isolated scope and link function. Controller in directives are not Controllers with `ng-controller`. They're made to expose an api to others directives. And they don't have scopes objects. The simplest way of writting reusable directive are isolated scopes and binding.

Comment: hmmm, I think i got a mistake, but when i remove the controller: from directive, my select list will show as empty. and when i fill them my list fill but i have 2 different scope :) 
for fetching data: i think you're right and i should modify my code.
but i still have a problem with 2 scope :( 
how about child scope? how can i make directive scope child of my controller?

Comment: just put `scope:true` but you will lose a lot in terms of reusability.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to watch for an attribute, but it's a read-only method, to write you have to use scope's binding.

Comment: thanks a lot dude, i am very confused about scope in angular :/
should we want to make a reusable directive, we should to use scope's binding.
thanks for your sample code :)

Comment: Directives are the hardest part of angularJS, the fact that directive's controller aren't the same than view's controller, doesn't help. However in most of case you only use scope's binding and link function.